# How to select rows from MySQL table with max values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with multiple rows for each customer and and a visit_date.  The visit date can be null as well.

My tables are as below:

customers:

```
id  |  name      | email 
1   |  John Doe1 | a.b@gmail.com 
2   |  John Doe2 | b.c@gmail.com
3   |  John Doe3 | x.y@gmail.com
```

store_customers

```
id |  customer_id  | store_id | email_optedin |  visit_date 
1  |     1         |   1      |   1         |   2015-11-30
2  |     1         |   2      |   1         |   2016-05-08
3  |     1         |   3      |   1         |    null
4  |     2         |   1      |   1         |   2015-04-30
5  |     2         |   2      |   1         |   2015-08-40
6  |     2         |   3      |   1         |   2015-12-12
7  |     3         |   1      |   1         |   null
8  |     3         |   2      |   1         |   null
9  |     3         |   3      |   1         |   null
```

I am trying to retrieve customers who either have not had a visit to the any of the three stores or have not visited since a specified date (e.g. 2016-04-15).

I am expecting customers 2 and 3 but not 1.

I tried this query:

```
select distinct * from customers 
inner join store_customers on store_customers.customer_id = customers.id 
    where customers.email != '' and 
    store_customer.store_id in (1,2,3) and customers.emailStatus not in ('Unverified','Bounced','Spammed') 
    and 
    (
       store_customer.email_optedin = 1 
       and max(store_customers.visit_date) <= '2016-04-15'  
       or account_customer.visit_date is null
    );
```

This does not work.  I somehow need to, for the set of store ids), I need to select customers who have either not had any visit (all nulls for visit date for the specified stores) or the if one or more visit dates are available then compare the max date to the specified date.

I found similar questions but none of the answers has worked for me, mainly because of the requirement of selecting either those customers who have no visit or if they do atleast one, then to compare the latest visit date from the set of stores in the joined table.

I am trying to do this all in one query but if that is not possible then I can break it up as well.  I also do not want to change the order of joins because there are many other things added on to this query and changing the order of joins may become a problem.

I really appreciate any help that can be provided.

Regards,

Waqar

Comment: I forgot to mention that I would expect the query to return customers 2 and 3.

Comment: "or account_customer.visit_date is null": that table is not part of the JOIN...

Comment: sorry.  account_customer is a typo.  It should be store_customers.  From the store_customer table, I am expecting row 6 (for customer_id 2) and one of rows 7,8,9 because those three rows are about the same customer_id (3).

Comment: max is not valid anywhere but in `SELECT`, `HAVING`, and (sometimes) `ORDER BY` clauses. I also question whenever I see `AND` and `OR` operators that have not had their order of operation explicitly set by `()`. That said, try `LEFT JOIN`, move most of your store_customers conditions into the join's conditions, and change the `max <=`  to `visit_date >`

Comment: Is it possible for you to setup a SQLFiddle?

Comment: Note that `distinct *` is a nonsensical construct

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT

        customers.id,
        customers.name,
        MAX(store_customers.visit_date)

    FROM

    customers LEFT JOIN store_customers on customers.id = store_customers.customer_id

    GROUP BY customers.id,customers.name

    HAVING MAX(store_customers.visit_date) < '2016-04-15' OR MAX(store_customers.visit_date) IS NULL
```